# Need to move code from hosted svn repo to production server

Tags: svn, export, tortoisesvn

I was going to do an export but since the repo is externally hosted svn it's a https:// address which is not allowed with export command(torotoise svn). How do i move the code? (The production server is another externally hosted address).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be I do not understand you correctly, but of course you can use the export-command of tortoiseSVN with https://

Have you tried it? What is your exact error message?

Ohterwise you can use the commandline:

```
svn export <YOUR_REPO_URL> <PATH(optional)>
```